# ECS Task Access Denied to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-ecs

I have an IAM role set for my task with the following permissions, yet I get **access denied** trying to access the buckets.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/Templates/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::anotherBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The container instance has a role with the standard  `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role` policy.

I seem to be able to read and write to folders under from bucket/ like bucket/00001, BUT I can't read from bucket/Templates.

Ive redeployed the permissions and the tasks repeatedly (using terraform) but nothing changes.  Ive added logging to the app to ensure it's using the correct bucket and path / keys.

I'm stumped.  Anyone got a clue what I might have missed here?

Thanks

PS: It just occurred to me, the files in the buckets I cant access I copy there using a script.  This is done using credentials other than the creds the task is using.

`aws s3 cp ..\Api\somefiles\000000000001\ s3://bucket/000000000001 --recursive --profile p
    aws s3 cp ..\Api\somefiles\Templates\000000000001\ s3://bucket/Templates/000000000001 --recursive --profile p`

I was using -acl bucket-owner-full-control on the cp command but I removed that to see if would help - it didnt.  Maybe I need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  Found an old sample from a previous employer :)  I needed a permission for List* explicitly, separate from the other permissions.  I also needed to define the sids.

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "sid1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:HeadBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "sid2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 4):

It works now because you changed the Resource to match "*". 
Try adding the bucket itself as a resource, along with /* pattern:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "sid1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:HeadBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "sid2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::anotherBucket"
                "arn:aws:s3:::anotherBucket/*",
            ]
    }
]
```